# The existence of $f \in C^\infty(R^n)$ with $ f=0$ on closed $E$, otherwise $f>0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

This is problem 6.3 in 'Rudin's Functional analysis

> If $E$ is an arbitrary closed subeset of $R^n$, show that there is an $f \in C^\infty(R^n)$ such that $f(x)=0$ for every $x \in E$ and $f(x)>0$ for every other $x \in R^n$.

I managed to find a function $f_{N} \in C^N$ with $f(E)=0$ and $f(E^c)>0$ for any $N \in \mathbb{N}$. First, let's state the theorem 6.20 in Rudin's Functional analysis.

Theorem 6.20.
If $\Gamma$ is a collection of open sets in $R^n$ whose union is $\Omega$, then there exists a sequence $\{\psi_{i}\} \subset D(\Omega)$, with $\psi_{i} \geq 0$, such that

1. each $\psi_i$ has its support in some member of $\Gamma$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \psi_{i}(x)=1$ for every $ x \in \Omega$
3. To every compact $K \subset \Omega$ correspond an integer $m$ and an open set $W \supset K$ such that 
   $\psi_{1}(x)+...+\psi_{m}(x)=1$ for all $x \in W$.

The notation $D(\Omega)$ is the test function space of $\Omega$. Now let $U=E^c$. Then we can represent $U$ as follows.
$$U=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}K_{j}, K_{1} \subset K_{2} \subset K_{3} \subset ...$$
where $K$ is compact set.

Apply theorem to $U$ in place of $\Omega$. Then by (3),

$$\phi_{1}(x) = \psi_{1}(x)+...+\psi_{m}(x)=1$$
for every $x \in W \supset K_1$. Note that by (1) $\phi_{1}$ has compact support. Put $P_1=K_1$ and $P_2=K_2 \cup \mathrm{supp}(\phi_1)$. Then $P_2$ is compact. By (3),
$$\phi_{2}(x) = \psi_{1'}(x)+...+\psi_{n'}(x)=1$$
for every $x \in W' \supset P_2$. Repeteadly, set $P_n=K_n \cup \mathrm{supp}(\phi_{n-1})$. Then we have following properties.

1. $U=\cup _{i=1}^\infty P_{i}, P_{1} \subset P_2 \subset P_3 \subset ...$
2. $\phi_{n}(x)=1 $ on $P_n$, range of $\phi$ is $[0,1]$ and $\phi(x)=0$ on $E$.

Now, pick 
$$\phi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\phi_{n}(x)}{2^n}$$
Then $\phi(x) = 0$ on $E$ and $\phi(x)>0$ on $U$. Moreover, by the uniform convergence $\phi$ is continuous.

If we replace $1/2^n$ with more smaller number, we can get function $\phi_{N} \in C^{N}$ by dominated convergence theorem.

Unfortunately, my approach cannot be improved. Is there any approach?

Comment: Consider the distance from $x$ to $E$.

Comment: @Christoph I think that the hardest part is to show $C^\infty$. Isn't it $f(x)=d(x,E)$ differentiable? Although $K*f$ is differentiable for $K \in C^\infty$, the function $K*f$ seems to be useless.

Comment: you could replace $d(x,E)$ with $\max(0,d(x,E)-1)$ to have some safety zone where convolving with some smoothing kernel can mess without getting non-zero values on $E$. I have to admit I didn't think about it very careful..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of working with a sequence of functions on which a priori you can't control all their derivatives together, you can work with only one function, appropriately translated and then normalize the sum to make it $C^{\infty}$.

For each $x \in U$, choose $r_x > 0$ such that the open ball $B(x,r_x)$ sits in $U$. Then ${B(x,\frac{r_x}{2})}_{x \in U}$ is an open cover of $U$ and so it has a countable subcover $B(x_i, \frac{r_i}{2})$ such that $U = \cup_{i} B(x_i, \frac{r_i}{2}) = \cup_{i} B(x_i, r_i)$.

Take some smooth function $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ satisfying $\phi(x) = 1$ for all $|x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ that is supported in $B_1(0)$ and consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \phi \left( \frac{x - x_i}{r_i} \right)$. Choose $c_n > 0$ appropriately that converge to zero fast enough so that the sum and all its derivatives will converge uniformly.

Comment: How can we say that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n \phi(\frac{x-x_{n}}{r_{n}})>0$ whenever $x \in U$?

Comment: Oh, I understand that. You pick balls with $U=\cup_{i}B_{r_{i}}(x_{i})=\cup_{i}B_{r_{i}/2}(x_{i})$. right? but is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit sloppy. I need $U = \cup_{i} B_{\frac{r_i}{2}}(x_i)$. This is always possible.

Comment: Oh, I see. That is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, it seems that it doesn't work. If I take $U = \cup_{i} B_{\frac{r_i}{2}}(x_i)$, the function doesn't necessarily vanish on $E$. One needs to start a priori with a function that is positive on $B_1(0)$ and vanishes outside in order for the argument to work. I'm modifying it right now...

Comment: No, we can. Let $\{x_{i}\}$ be all rational numbers in $U$. For each $x_{i}$, there is an $r_{i}$ such that $B_{r_{i}}(x_{i}) \subset U$. Then $U=\cup_{i}B_{r_{i}/2}(x_{i})=\cup_{i}B_{r_{i}}(x_{i})$,

Comment: I mean, yeah, we really need a cover such that $U = \cup_i B_{\frac{r_i}{2}}(x_i) = \cup_i B_{r_i}(x_i)$ for the argument to work so I modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: All right. Anyway, we done. Thanks!